# Proof of $\vdash P \rightarrow (Q\lor P)$

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I was wondering how to go about proving this tautology. It seems quite simple to just answer:

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{[P]^*}{Q\lor P}\lor_I}{P\rightarrow (Q\lor P)} \to_I^* $$

Is this sufficient or does one also have to deduce the implication $P\rightarrow (Q\lor P)$ from EFQ?

Comment: That looks sufficient to me -- though of course whether you need more boilerplate for _writing it down_ as a formal proof depends on the nitty-gritty details of how your logical rules are set up, which you haven't shared. There doesn't seem to be any _natural_ reason to need EFQ here, though.

Comment: The requirements on the proof is dependent on which inference rules and which propositions you may use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivation is absolutely correct! There is no need for EFQ, the rules $\lor_I$ ($\lor$-introduction) and $\to_I$ ($\to$-introduction) that you have used in your derivation are sufficient to prove $P \to (Q \lor P)$.

Remark: This means that $P \to (Q \lor P)$ is provable not only in classical and intuitionistic logic, but also in minimal logic.

Comment: No, if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false then $Q\lor\neg P$ is false and therefore the implication does not hold. It was $P\rightarrow (Q\lor P)$ that should be proven.

Comment: @skyking: I agree with you but there was a typo in the formula in my answer. The correct formula to prove is $P \to (Q \lor P)$, as you can see in the original question.

Comment: What is the difference between classical and minimal logic?

Comment: @David - In classical logic the inference rule _reductio ad absurdom_ ([RAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum)) is valid. In intuitionistic logic, only a special case of RAA is valid: _ex falso quodlibet_ ([EFQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)). In minimal logic, EFQ is not valid either. So, minimal logic is a fragment of intuitionistic logic, which in turn is a fragment of classical logic.